# SonarQube 6.0 pdf Report

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube 6.0 and try to export the Analysis report as pdf. 
Unfortunality I'm getting "Report is not available. At least one analysis is required after installing the plugin."

Comment: Please read the stack overflow tour to know more about this site.

Comment: And did you already executed an analysis?

Comment: Yes, I executed an analysis but it doesn't help. I' ve used the pdf report plugin version 1.4 from the site : http://www.sonarplugins.com/pdfreport . Maybe there is something wrong ?  Thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use this plugin because that version is only compatible with SonarQube 4.5.7. The plugin is replaced by the [Governance](http://www.sonarplugins.com/governance) plugin (commercial product, not available separately) but that version is only compatible with [SonarQube 5.6](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix). The only option you have today is build the plugin yourself. But watch out: the available APIs can change between the different SonarQube versions.

Answer (score 0):

I have Created my own report using **sonar-ws-client** if you like you can use it and even you can create your own **.pdf** report as I created.

Note: Before using following code please import **sonar-ws-client** into your classpath.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.sonar.wsclient.SonarClient;
import org.sonar.wsclient.issue.Issue;
import org.sonar.wsclient.issue.IssueClient;
import org.sonar.wsclient.issue.IssueQuery;
import org.sonar.wsclient.issue.Issues;

public class SonarReport {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String login = "admin";
        String password = "admin";

        SonarClient client = SonarClient.create("http://10.20.120.47:9000");
        client.builder().login(login);
        client.builder().password(password);

        List<Issue> issuesList = new ArrayList<Issue>();
        IssueClient issueClient = client.issueClient();
        Issues issues = null;

        IssueQuery query = IssueQuery.create();
        //query.severities("BLOCKER","CRITICAL", "MAJOR");
        query.resolved(false);
        query.urlParams().put("types", "VULNERABILITY");


        int issueCount = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++) {

            query.pageIndex(i);
            query.pageSize(500);

            issues = issueClient.find(query);
            issuesList.addAll(issues.list());

            System.out.println("In progress ...");
        }

        createHTMLReport(issuesList);
    }

    private static void createHTMLReport(List<Issue> issueList) {

        try {
            String filename = "SonarIssues.html";

            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            // Construct report data
            Map<String,String> tableData = cunstructTableData(issueList);

            if(tableData!= null)
            {
                // HTML page construction
                builder.append("<!DOCTYPE>").append("\n");
                builder.append("<html>").append("\n");
                builder.append("<head>").append("\n");
                builder.append("<style>").append("\n");
                builder.append("table, th, td {").append("\n");
                builder.append(" border: 1px solid black;").append("\n");
                builder.append(" border-collapse: collapse;font-size: 13px !important;").append("\n");
                builder.append("}").append("\n");
                builder.append("th, td {  ").append("\n");
                builder.append(" padding: 10px;  ").append("\n");
                builder.append("}").append("\n");
                builder.append("table#alter tr:nth-child(even) { ").append("\n");
                builder.append("background-color: #eee;").append("\n");
                builder.append("}").append("\n");
                builder.append("table#alter tr:nth-child(odd) {  ").append("\n");
                builder.append("    background-color: #fff;  ").append("\n");
                builder.append("}  ").append("\n");
                builder.append("table#alter th {  ").append("\n");
                builder.append("    color: white; ").append("\n");
                builder.append("    background-color: gray;  ").append("\n");
                builder.append("}").append("\n");
                builder.append(" table {margin-bottom:50px;}").append("\n");
                builder.append(" table tr .title {background:#5f9be3;color:#fff;font-weight:bold;padding:5px; width:100px;   }").append("\n");
                builder.append(" table tr .text {padding-left:10px;}").append("\n");
                builder.append("</style>").append("\n");
                builder.append("</head>").append("\n");
                builder.append("<body style='font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;'> ").append("\n");

                // Application version info
                builder.append("<table class='projectInfo' style='width:26%; margin-bottom:10px'><tr><td style='border-color: #fff;width: 86%;' class='title'> Project Version: v4.4.0</td>").append("\n");
                builder.append("</tr></table>").append("\n");

                // Table header info
                builder.append("<table class='statisticsInfo'><tr><td style='border-color: #fff;width: 86%;' class='title'>Total No. of issues:</td>").append("\n");
                builder.append("<td style='background-color: yellow;border-color: #fff;' class='text'>"+tableData.get("TotalNumberOfIssues")+"</td></tr>").append("\n");

                builder.append("<tr><td style='border-color: #fff;width: 86%;' class='title'>Blocker Issues:</td>").append("\n");
                builder.append("<td style='background-color: yellow;border-color: #fff;' class='text'>"+tableData.get("BlockerIssues")+"</td></tr>").append("\n");

                builder.append("<tr><td style='border-color: #fff;width: 86%;' class='title'>Critical Issues: </td>").append("\n");
                builder.append("<td style='background-color: yellow;border-color: #fff;' class='text'>"+tableData.get("CriticalIssues")+"</td></tr>").append("\n");

                builder.append("<tr><td style='border-color: #fff;width: 86%;' class='title'>Major Issues: </td>").append("\n");
                builder.append("<td style='background-color: yellow;border-color: #fff;' class='text'>"+tableData.get("MajorIssues")+"</td></tr>").append("\n");

                builder.append("<tr><td style='border-color: #fff;width: 86%;' class='title'>Minor Issues: </td>").append("\n");
                builder.append("<td style='background-color: yellow;border-color: #fff;' class='text'>"+tableData.get("MinorIssues")+"</td></tr></table>").append("\n");

                builder.append("<table id='alter'>").append("\n");
                // Header part
                builder.append("<tr><th>File name</th>");
                builder.append("<th>Severity</th>");
                builder.append("<th>Status</th>");
                builder.append("<th>Message</th></tr> ");

                builder.append(tableData.get("TableData")).append("\n");

                builder.append("</table>").append("\n");
                builder.append("</body>").append("\n");
                builder.append("</html>").append("\n");

                pw.println(builder.toString());
                pw.close();
            }

            System.out.println("HTML Report has been generated!");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);

        }
    }

    private static Map<String, String> cunstructTableData(List<Issue> issueList) {

         Map<String,String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
         StringBuilder tableData = new StringBuilder();

         int blockerIssues = 0;
         int criticalIssues = 0;
         int majorIssues = 0;
         int minorIssues = 0;

         result.put("TotalNumberOfIssues", String.valueOf(issueList.size()));

         for (int i = 0; i < issueList.size(); i++) {

            String[] className = issueList.get(i).componentKey().split("/");

            tableData.append("<tr><td>"+className[className.length -1]+"</td>");
            tableData.append("<td>"+issueList.get(i).severity()+"</td>");
            tableData.append("<td>"+issueList.get(i).status()+"</td>");
            tableData.append("<td>"+issueList.get(i).message()+"</td></tr> ").append("\n");

            switch(issueList.get(i).severity()){

                case "BLOCKER":
                    ++blockerIssues;
                    break;
                case "CRITICAL":
                    ++criticalIssues;
                    break;
                case "MAJOR":
                    ++majorIssues;
                    break;
                case "MINOR":
                    ++minorIssues;
                    break;
            }
         }

         result.put("MajorIssues",String.valueOf(majorIssues));
         result.put("CriticalIssues",String.valueOf(criticalIssues));
         result.put("BlockerIssues",String.valueOf(blockerIssues));
         result.put("MinorIssues",String.valueOf(minorIssues));

         result.put("TableData", tableData.toString());

        return result;
    }

}
```